# Is there any research and/or guidelines on the amount of epochs depending on NN architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am interested is there any research done and if there are general guidelines for the number of epochs needed to train the neural network optimally.

Does anybody have material to share on this?

EDIT: I've realised that it would be good to explain a reason behind the question. I am a bit annoyed by the early stopping technique as it usually implies that the network is too powerful if the validation loss starts to diverge from the training loss.

It feels that it is a better approach to make a simpler model and train it long enough until it generalises better.

For example, [this guy](https://youtu.be/bLqJHjXihK8?t=829) shows that generalisation may continue after reaching sufficiently low loss.

But it is completely unclear when a "proper" generalisation should kick in. Are 100 epochs enough? What about 1000? 10000?

How does it depend on my number of parameters? Structure? Type?

Answer (score 2):

There is no golden number, or even parametric form. As you may already be aware, early stopping is the name of the game. You always want to monitor your in-sample versus out-of-sample performance.

[image]

This paper seems useful: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/stop_tricks1997.pdf

Comment: The paper by Prechelt is gold. Often overlooked though... Great you referenced it!

Comment: I personally dislike the use of early stopping as it implies that the model is too powerful and/or there is too little data. Then I would rather make the model simpler.

Comment: I recommend watching this video https://youtu.be/VIRCybGgHts where Hinton explains (around 18. minute) why it is a bad idea to tailor the size of your model to your data instead of using a big model which may be better able to capture your problem if you regularize it properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is one guideline: Train so long as **both** the training and the validation error are decreasing.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.